# Unable to recover Hyperledger Fabric Orderer due to insufficient disk space

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

After performing Load Test on my Hyperledger Fabric, both of my Orderers ran out of disk space, which causes the Orderers not responding to any call.  I tried to free up the disk space by clearing the log and restart the Orderer but failed.  Below is the captured error.

Have anyone encountered the same issue and how to resolve?

```html
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [orderer/common/blockcutter] Ordered -> DEBU 5929 Enqueuing message into batch
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [orderer/kafka] processRegular -> DEBU 592a [channel: test] Ordering results: items in batch = 0, ok = true
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [orderer/kafka] processMessagesToBlocks -> DEBU 592b [channel: test] Successfully unmarshalled consumed message, offset is 14829. Inspecting type...
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [orderer/kafka] processTimeToCut -> DEBU 592c [channel: test] It's a time-to-cut message for block 2345
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [orderer/kafka] processTimeToCut -> DEBU 592d [channel: test] Nil'd the timer
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [fsblkstorage] retrieveBlockByNumber -> DEBU 592e retrieveBlockByNumber() - blockNum = [2344]
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileStream -> DEBU 592f newBlockfileStream(): filePath=[/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains/test/blockfile_000001], startOffset=[13754]
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [fsblkstorage] nextBlockBytesAndPlacementInfo -> DEBU 5930 Remaining bytes=[67089544], Going to peek [8] bytes
fabric-order    | 2018-03-31 03:15:38.370 UTC [fsblkstorage] nextBlockBytesAndPlacementInfo -> DEBU 5931 Returning blockbytes - length=[115], placementInfo={fileNum=[1], startOffset=[13754], bytesOffset=[13755]}
fabric-order    | panic: Error seeking to newest block for chain with non-zero height
fabric-order    |
fabric-order    | goroutine 22 [running]:
fabric-order    | panic(0xb31bc0, 0xc4202031b0)
fabric-order    |       /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
fabric-order    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ledger.CreateNextBlock(0x7fc67f4b0fc0, 0xc4200bad80, 0xc4202841e0, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc420202a40)
fabric-order    |       /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ledger/util.go:63 +0x4c3
fabric-order    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/multichain.(*chainSupport).CreateNextBlock(0xc4202f4c80, 0xc4202841e0, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc4207e0440)
fabric-order    |       /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/multichain/chainsupport.go:224 +0x81
fabric-order    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka.processTimeToCut(0xc420202730, 0x1231f60, 0xc4202f4c80, 0xc4203526f8, 0xc420bbf9a0, 0x39ed, 0x0, 0x0)
fabric-order    |       /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka/chain.go:410 +0x3e0
fabric-order    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka.(*chainImpl).processMessagesToBlocks(0xc4203526c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
fabric-order    |       /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka/chain.go:249 +0xa45
fabric-order    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka.startThread(0xc4203526c0)
fabric-order    |       /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka/chain.go:182 +0x981
fabric-order    | created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka.(*chainImpl).Start
fabric-order    |       /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/kafka/chain.go:94 +0x3f
fabric-order exited with code 2
```

Comment: which logs did you clear?

Comment: I executed below command on my orderer node.  truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd be curious to find the underlying cause of your problem (the ledger should tolerate running out of disk space gracefully), you should be able to recover your orderers through the following procedure:

1. Backup your existing orderers (especially their ledgers)
2. Delete the ledger directory (such as `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer`).
3. Specify the genesis method of file (ie, `ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file`) and pass in the original genesis block you bootstrapped your orderer with via `ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=<genesis.block or other name>`
4. Start the orderer, it should connect to Kafka and replay all of the transactions to reconstruct the ledger.  If you watch the log, or the ledger size, you should see it grow, and the container will be very active until it catches up to the current state.

Note, if your Kafka logs have expired since you started your network, this procedure will not work.  This is effectively the procedure you would follow to add a new orderer to the network.

Comment: Thanks for the info!!

found that my kafka is missing below settings...would this be the root cause?

KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1

Comment: Allowing the Kafka logs to expire is certainly not recommended, but it does not account for the error you are seeing within your orderer.  Although it is difficult to tell without examining the ledger directly, it appears that the block store was corrupted or deleted.

If your Kafka logs have expired as well, recovery may not be possible.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce the same situation.  I am able to recover the orderer node now after re-configuring the kafka with proper settings.  Thanks!!

Comment: @JasonYellick do you have an example of multiple orderers connected to a kafka cluster, that we can take a look? Whatever sample I found is one orderer and a kafka cluster. Thanks